# Remove categorical variable from ggplot density/histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a variable with 3 values: Male, Female, Unknown. For many parts of the analysis, I need to keep the unknown but I want to do a density/histogram comparing some scores WITHOUT the unknown. What else do I need to add to take out one of the values?

My data looks like this:

| GenderDescription | SATCompositeSuper |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| Female | 730 |
| Female | 780 |
| Male | 800 |
| Female | 1000 |
| Female | 1110 |
| Female | NA |
| Male | 1050 |
| Male | 950 |
| Unknown | 900 |
| Male | 780 |

Syntax:

```
  # Color by groups- gender
  master_df %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  library(ggplot2)
  ggplot(master_df, aes(x=SATCompositeSuper, na.rm=TRUE, color=GenderDescription, 
  fill=GenderDescription)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.5, position="identity")
  +geom_density(alpha=.2)
```

Current Output (because I wasn't thinking about the Unknown) is this:
[image]

Comment: Try replacing `master_df` with `filter(master_df, GenderDescription != "Unknown)` as the data object for the ggplot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't produce the plot that you showed in your post however, there are two ways I can think of filtering out the Unknown

First, you can filter out the data before you plot the data

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyverse)
 master_df <- master_df %>%
   drop_na() %>%
   filter(GenderDescription != "Unknown")
   
 ggplot(master_df, aes(x=SATCompositeSuper, na.rm=TRUE, color=GenderDescription, fill=GenderDescription)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.5, position="identity") +
   geom_density(alpha=.2)
```

And the second is to filter the data as you're plotting

```
 ggplot(data=master_df[!master_df$GenderDescription %in% c("Unknown"),], aes(x=SATCompositeSuper, na.rm=TRUE, color=GenderDescription, fill=GenderDescription)) + 
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha=0.5, position="identity") +
   geom_density(alpha=.2)
```

Comment: Do you mean my graph doesn't look like the data I posted? I'm trying to make sure I'm not missing something else. I didn't post all the data because it's 14K rows so I was hoping the idea of the data made sense. Is it better for me to post all of it when I ask? Still new on here so want to help those that I'm asking for help to better understand...or catch bigger issues because that's entirely possible at this point.

Comment: I would just say that this isn't the full dataset. Additionally, you could try to make an example that somewhat looks like the real data. The resulting plot from the example data just doesn't look like plot you posted in your question so started to make me second guess my answer

Comment: I got the second filter to work great. The first is somehow including the unknown still so I'll go with the second route for now. The error in the first could be user error on my part.Thanks so much for helping!!

Comment: @KathyGodwin I didn't add the required library for the first filter. Maybe that will help. If my answer answered your question feel free to upvote accept the answer